# Modbus: router to a PC

Tags: c, linux, ssh, modbus

I have a Cisco router running Yocto distr (the name of platform is called Guest-Os, a embedded linux system), and I have installed [lib-modbus](http://libmodbus.org/). Currently, I am connecting to the router via serial Com port ssh connection using my PC. I want to see if the modbus library works or not in the router. The library contains two pre-compiled C program call unit-test-server.c, and unit-test-client.c.

Normally in my PC linux machine, I could open up two terminal, one running unit-test-server.c, while the second terminal running the unit-test-client.c, and it reports succesful. However, in my case, I want to see whether this lib-modbus is sucessful or not, but I couldn't open up two terminals in the router (only 1 ssh connection).

Is it possible for me to test this modbus connection with my PC linux as a server, and then the router as client? If I want to do this connection, do I need to hook them up using a ethernet cable?

Comment: best policy is to hook up two PCs using a RS-232 cable to a serial port on each PC.  One PC had the MODBUS hardware.  The other PC has the test program.

Comment: what do you mean modbus hardware